# Why does it return null in my binary search tree, search method

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I don't know why I am getting null in my method ?

```
public Node<E> search(int data, Node<E> start){
    Node<E> foundNode = null;

    if(data < start.getData()){
        search(data, start.getLeftNode());
    }

    if(data > start.getData()){
        search(data, start.getRightNode());
    }

    if(data == start.getData()){
        foundNode = start;
    }

    return foundNode;

}
```

if I put `System.out.println(foundNode);` before the return statement I get the node but when it returns it I get null!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the return statements for the recursive function calls:
`search(data,start.getLeftNode());` and `search(data, start.getRightNode());`

Your method would only work when there are no recursive calls executed and if they are executed still `foundNode` that is returned remains `NULL`, since its a local variable.

So, correct code is:

```
public Node<E> search(int data, Node<E> start){
Node<E> foundNode = null;

if(data < start.getData()){
    return search(data, start.getLeftNode());
}

if(data > start.getData()){
    return search(data, start.getRightNode());
}

if(data == start.getData()){
    foundNode = start;
}
return foundNode;
```

}

Comment: I don't know how did I missed it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method:

```
private Node search(String name, Node node){
    if(node != null){
        if(node.name().equals(name)){
           return node;
        } else {
            Node foundNode = search(name, node.left);
            if(foundNode == null) {
                foundNode = search(name, node.right);
            }
            return foundNode;
         }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```